# Explanation and all options for $options in Symfony form builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have tried a lot and could be able to find what are the various available options which i can use for `$options` in array for form builder.

I know that options are different for

1. fields
2. entity
3. collection

But could not be able to find what are those for these categories and their explanations

```
->add('name','text',array());
->add('user','entity',array());
->add('user','collection',array());
```

Is there any resource which can tell what options i can use in above cases

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the documentation itself is available here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types.html. Click on a field type to learn about its options.